# vite-tsconfig-paths resolves the paths correctly but vite cannot find the files - though they exist

Tags: vite

I try to use paths from tsconfig in my vite config but it doesn't work. Vite tells me it cannot find the files though it resolves them correctly as I found when using DEBUG=vite-tsconfig-paths to get debug info when running

Then it says e.g

> vite-tsconfig-paths resolved: {   id: '@common/AssetLoader',
> importer: 'C:/Users/tom/data/m3d/frontend/modeller/src/main.ts',
> resolvedId:
> 'C:/Users/tom/data/m3d/frontend/common/src/AssetLoader.ts',
> configPath: 'C:/Users/tom/data/m3d/frontend/tsconfig.json' } +9ms

which is perfect and I can also open the Assetloader file with that path

But later in the console it says

> Error: The following dependencies are imported but could not be
> resolved:
>
> @common/AssetLoader (imported by
> C:/Users/tom/data/m3d/frontend/modeller/src/components/ViewS.vue?id=0)

and the same for other files. So I dont understand whats going on since it seesm to resolve the path correctly but then cannot find the existing files

My vite config is like this:

```
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';

export default defineConfig({. 
   plugins: [
      vue(),
      tsconfigPaths({ root: './' })// also tried without parameter
   ]
})
```

Any ideas someone?
Cheers
Tom

Comment: Found a workaround by using
resolve: {
      alias: {
         /* Note: Not entirely sure why I need this in spite of using tsconfigPaths but so it is. 
         See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75770948/vite-tsconfig-paths-resolves-the-paths-correctly-but-vite-cannot-find-the-files for what happens without these aliases */
         '@common': normalizePath(path.resolve(__dirname, './common/src')),
         '@modeller': normalizePath(path.resolve(__dirname, './modeller/src')),
      },
   },
as part of vite config. Thoguh not sure why this is needed.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever solve this beyond a workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But we were very busy so didn't invest real time anymore. Best of luck. Let me know if u figure sth out

Answer (score 1):

After running into this myself, I found a config option "loose" that seems to have fixed it, though I don't honestly know why.

```
plugins: [
    viteTsConfigPaths({
      loose: true,
      root: '../../',
    }),
  ],
```

Comment: From plugin docs:

Disable strictness that limits path resolution to TypeScript and JavaScript importers.

Useful if you want imports in Vue templates to be resolved, but don't want to use allowJs in your tsconfig, for example.

In other words, when loose: true is used, any file that gets transpiled into JavaScript will have its imports resolved by this plugin.

So....  It seems this is needed when vite resolves from a Vue SFC.